# String parsing error while writing an xml file in php

Tags: php, xml

I am writing an sitemap file with php code.I am able to write the file correctly according to requirement.But i want to add namespace tag to starting node of xml file,I tried it doing by the code.But got following error

```
Uncaught exception Exception with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'
```

following is my xml structure

```
<urlset>
    <url>
      <loc>url1</loc>
    </url>
..
..
</urlset>
```

There are number of url fragments under the parent node as urlset.I want to add namespace tag for sitemaps to urlset node.Thats the only thing i am not able to.Xml file is quite bigger,i am not able to do it manually..

following is my xml formation code

```
<?php

     //Create Database connection
  $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'dbname');

   if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
      }
    /* if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
        printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    } else {
        printf("Current character set: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());
    }
    */
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
    for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    // used to be: $query='select tablecolname1 from tablename limit 10000';
    $start = $i * 50000;
    $query = "select Siteurl from tablename limit $start, 50000";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);  

//Create SimpleXMLElement object
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $mydata = $xml->addChild('url');
$mydata->loc=$row['Siteurl'];
//htmlentities(strip_tags($mydata->loc=$row['Siteurl']), ENT_COMPAT,'utf-8');
    }
    // used to be: $fp = fopen("folder/file2.xml","wb");
    $fp = fopen("site/sitemap$i.xml","wb");
    fwrite($fp,utf8_encode($xml->asXML()));
    fclose($fp);
}


    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<urlset/>');

    ?>
```

Please guide me on how to add namespace tag to urlset tag..

Comment: Show us the whole XML please. Or the code line which the error reffers.

Comment: error is in urlset node

Comment: The first <urlset/> (the one with the namespace definition) is not closed. So it is not a valid xml document.

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleXMLElement` expects as parameter "a well-formed XML string" according to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php).
`'<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">'` is not such a string.

You can build a XML from PHP in (at least) two (simple) ways:

- either only by echoing the content you want in your XML file (tags included):

  ```
    header('Content-Type:text/xml');
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    echo '<urlset xmlns="...">';
    ...
    echo '</urlset>';
  ```
- or by using the SimpleXML object and building the DOM tree (see example #10 in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)):

  ```
    header('Content-Type:text/xml');
    $xml=new SImpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
    $urlset=$xml->addChild('urlset');
    $urlset->addAttribute('xmlns','...');
    ...
    echo $xml->asXML();
  ```